# Get the pages of a multipage meeting workspace

Tags: sharepoint, moss, sitetemplate

I currently do some testings on the multipage meeting workspace template to check whether it fit our needs to be the base template for our projects.

As you might know, a multipage meeting workspace is designed to be able to manage several dates within a single workspace and to display either pages that are only related to a certain date or pages that should appear on every date.

If you examine a multipage meeting workspace with SharePoint Designer you can see that there is a library which contains all the pages of the workspace. Pages that are displayed on every date are stored in the root folder, pages that are only displayed on single dates are stored in folders which are named with the according date.

So now we come to my problem. In order to set the permission for a single page that is displayed on each date, I iterate over the page library to find the page I want to change the permissions on. Strangely, the ListItemCollection of the library pretend to contain the number of pages I expected it to contain. But when I then iterate over the collection it only returns the pages that are attached to the actual date. Neither does it return the pages which should be displayed on every date nor the pages for the other dates.

I have already tried to get the pages by using SPSecruity.RunWithElevatedPrivilges() and with impersonation as the system account. I've also tried to get them via a command line application without using any context information. It seems as the behavior, that you can only get the items which are related to a certain date, is also followed by the object model.

So how could I get all pages of a multipages meeting workspace regardless of the actual date???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pages for this kind of events get created only when a user tries to access them.  This is by design, and the only solution I found was to try and access the page via the website (or some emulation) and then try to access them by code.

Regarding Flo's Comment, I fount the source for this on Microsoft Sharepoint 2007 Development unleashed (sams, ISBN 0-672-32903-4). on p 101 says:

> CAUTION
>
> Obtaining data from recurring meetings
>   can be tricky. You might encounter
>   situations in which your code attempts
>   to access a list item for a meeting
>   occurrence that has not yet been
>   provisioned in the Meeting Series
>   list. To ensure that the individual
>   instance has been created, you can
>   make a dummy web request to the
>   instance’s home page, for example:
>   http://server/sites/mymeeting/default.aspx?InstanceID=20061012

If you find another way, please post it It will save us lots of effort!!!

Comment: Mh, I cannot imagine that this is really the only way to be able to access these files.

Comment: Flo, I just edited my answer, adding the source for my statement.

Nicolas.

Comment: Puh, that's really a little bit shocking. ;) I will update my post if I found another way.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch an event on workspace creation moment and at the event set permissions programmatically. You may want to know more about [event receivers](http://www.davehunter.co.uk/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=f0e16a1a-6fa9-4130-bcab-baeb97ccc4ff&ID=69) or [setting permissions programmatically](http://blogs.msdn.com/robgruen/archive/2007/11/15/how-to-programmatically-set-permissions-on-files-folders-in-a-sharepoint-document-library.aspx).

Those pages you mentioned are items added to a list called "Meeting Series"
[alt text http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/8963/ss20090528181724.png](http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/8963/ss20090528181724.png)

It contains following fields:

[alt text http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/351/ss20090528181819.png](http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/351/ss20090528181819.png) [alt text http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/7857/ss20090528181852.png](http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/7857/ss20090528181852.png)

Example data from 1 item (not in tat order as columns are mentioned):

```
3   0x001C4383A41E441842A2A27CA249FED28F    Meeting Series  Recurrence  2009-05-28 18:11:20 2009-05-28 18:11:12 1073741823;#Sistēmas konts  1073741823;#Sistēmas konts  1   1   512 1.0 0   0   Recurrence  Recurrence  3   100.000000000000    {A6E54DB5-3A60-464B-A9A0-D314B49C41E8}  3;#test2/Recurrence/Lists/Meeting Series/1_2.000    3;#test2/Recurrence/Lists/Meeting Series    3;#2009-05-28 18:11:20  3;#2009-05-28 18:11:20  3;#0    0x7fffffffffffffff  3;#1_2.000  3;#{6BE299E5-E81F-40A8-80B2-41494DF0353C}   3;# 3;#{965D0DB3-1AE0-4C23-B006-FB4FC1FE1AB7}   1_2.000 3   1_2.000 1_2.000 /test2/Recurrence/Lists/Meeting Series/1_2.000  http://test:10000/test2/Recurrence/Lists/Meeting%20Series/1_2.000   1_2 3;# 1   1   2   {D8839339-6DDA-48A6-B3B7-FBCA58C8B436}  2009-06-03 19:00:00 2009-06-03 19:00:00 (null)  (null)  (null)  0   1   (null)  0   0   0   2009-05-28 18:10:57 (null)  http://test:10000/test2/Lists/Calendar, Kalendārs   2009-06-03 19:00:00
```